# How can I change my system audio output / input device through Node JS (or command line)

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, powershell, electron

I'm attempting to build a little dashboard for my computer in Electron and something that would be really useful for me is having the ability to change my audio output at the click of a button (on the electron app). Is there any way this is possible through the Node API or a command through Command Prompt/PowerShell? I'm open to any options that would allow this outside of Node/Electron/CMD as well

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1054594/switching-default-audio-device-with-a-batch-file) link might have what you are looking for (CMD example). To execute cmd/bash you can use `child_process`/`node-cmd`/`shelljs` packages.